# ADDRESS function nested in SUM returns Err: 502

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, spreadsheet

When working on one problem, I came upon something that confuses me and was hoping for some clarification.

I am trying to use the `SUM()` function in a very round about way.

The formula

```
=SUM(ADDRESS(ROW(blahblah), COLUMN(blahblah)) : ADDRESS(RoW(blahblah), COLUMN(blahblah)))
```

throws an Err:502

When I apply the `INDIRECT()` to the `ADDRESS()`s it works great.

```
=SUM(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(blahblah), COLUMN(blahblah))  : INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(blahblah), COLUMN(blahblah)))
```

returns a value that checks out.

What confuses me is that using when pulling the nested function apart the `ADDRESS()` functions will give a valid cell reference (EX: `$B$4`) but the when added to the guts of a `SUM()` the `SUM()` pukes up an error code.  So why would there need to be an additional `INDIRECT()` to make an `ADDRESS()` work when nested in a `SUM()`?

Any thoughts at all?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `ADDRESS()` function does just that.  It provides a reference to a cell and not the contents of the cell.  The `INDIRECT()` function will take the cell references and provide the cell contents so the `SUM()` function works properly.

Comment: And to be clear, the output of the `ADDRESS()` function is a string (i.e., text), not a regular range reference that `SUM()` can take as an argument.